# How does tc work with iptables?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

The common way of traffic shaping is creating a classful qdisc on a network card and create a class and filter under the root qdisc.  Then use iptables to set marks on the packets.  But since iptables has different chains to represent each step to process a packet.  Which chain does tc work with, prerouting, input, forward, output or postrouting?

Comment: AFAIK `tc` works directly on the queues for each physical network interface. In other words, before (ingress) or after (egress) processing with `iptables` in the various chains happens. So the two are completely separate, and only communicate via the marks on the packets.